# Does alsa depend on the kernel version?

Tags: linux-kernel, alsa

Lately I had nothing but trouble with my sound setup. The full chain looks like this:

```
alsa (pulse plugin)-> pulseaudio (jack plugin) -> jackd -> firewire soundcard
```

This works fine, except for flash in firefox and Chrome. I have reason to believe that the tail end of the chain is okay, because every other source of audio, using pulse or jackd directly works fine.

On the front end I made some experiments, like connecting alsa directly to jackd, but this also causes trouble with flashplayer: playback stops after like 20 seconds and firefox freezes.

This made me believe that there is something wrong with the alsa stuff.

Now I do have a custom kernel (3.8.2) but the rest of the system uses regular debian "stable" stuff. Can it be that the kernel is "too new" for the alsa libs?

Comment: I don't think it's very likely. There is a dependence the other way around, though.

Comment: There can be a dependence if you use some special firmware but apparently, that's not your case if you can use your soundcard for others purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ALSA drivers are part of the kernel, and thus depend on the kernel version.

However, in your pipeline, you are not using ALSA drivers.

The ALSA library, PulseAudio, and Jack are all userspace programs that are not affected by the kernel version.

The only kernel drivers used are the FireWire drivers, which did not have any relevant changes recently.

Comment: I was not so much worried about the drivers, but the plugins, like the pulse plugin or (in an alternative setup) the jack plugin. Are these independant of the kernel?